# CORS error only when not 'await' in a ASP WebApi project

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

In a C# WebApi project plus angular js, the browser shows "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".
I enabled the CORS in starup class:

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

In fact, other controllers in the same project are working fine. After debugging, I see that the problem is when I start a task without the 'await'. In the controller, I need to send an email at end of the process, but I did not want to wait for the sending, it is not important, it is just a notification, so I throw the sending task without waiting. In this case, the CORS problem appears when the service is called from angularjs. In reality, the service is called and it works, but the post function of angularjs returns error and the browser console shows the CORS message.

```
 public async Task SaveData(DemoModel form)
 {
    ... code for saving data...
    SendEmailDemo();
 }
```

However, if I add the 'await' word and wait for sending the email, everything works fine.

```
 public async Task SaveData(DemoModel form)
 {
    ... code for saving data...
    await SendEmailDemo();
 }
```

I am confused and I am not clear about the reason. Somebody can explain what I am missing?